# How does Go deal with HTTP keep-alive?

Tags: http, tcp, go

I understand the rule that, if client and server both support persistent connection, they can use it through a `Connection:keep-alive` header in the first request. After that, both client and server will still keep the underlying TCP connection open when they are done with the first request/response, and then use the same connection in the following requests/responses.

What I'm not clear about is the programming model. Consider the following client code in go:

```
resp, _ := client.Get("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
// do some other things
resp, _ = client.Get("http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions")
```

As far as I know, `keep-alive` is the default strategy in HTTP/1.1.

**Q1: Do these two requests use the same TCP connection?**

On the server side:

When one request comes, the Go HTTP framework dispatches it to a handler, then due to keep-alive, the framework should prepare for the next request on the same TCP connection. However I don't see any block-mode read code in a handler. So,

**Q2: Does the Go HTTP framework use some kind of non-block mode to deal with keep-alive?**

I mean, a handler will not block for reading, but just return when done with a request, then the framework will poll each non-block TCP connection, if one of them has data arrive, it dispatches it to an associated handler, and so on. Only when the request has a header of `Connection:Close`, the framework will close the TCP connection when the handler returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q1: Do these two requests use the same TCP connection?

Yes, if the connection wasn't closed by the server, the http.Transport can re-use the connection in the default configuration.

> Q2: Does the go http framework use some kind of non-block mode to deal with keep-alive?

The go HTTP Server handles keepalive connections be default. There's no such thing as a HTTP "non-block mode". It handles requests and responses on a single connection in a serial manner as described by the HTTP specification.

Comment: Logically, when go http framework is done with handling a request, it should read from tcp to wait the next request. I think **read** will block until data comes, but I don't perceive the framework blocks. So how is this implemented?

Comment: @H.W.Du: if you want to know how it's implemented, read the source. The actual loop that handles requests is currently in `func (c *conn) serve()` from [http/server.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/server.go)